# Wordpress displaying old PHP errors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website that has been created by other party. When I was editing a template file and checking a minor change, a PHP error appeared on top of the page (literally the first line in the document, above )

```
[12-Jun-2017 19:08:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/SITENAME/public_html/wp-content/themes/booklovers/widgets/top10.php on line 8
```

I do know what it means, but it appears that the error itself is not the issue. The time does not change, it constantly displays 19:08:58. I've also tried renaming/moving the file to see what happens - and nothing happens at all. It is being executed, because the page results with a white screen when I put exit; in it. Renaming made no difference. Checking this path by file_exists() called in index results with false. In my opinion it has something to do with Wordpress, because if I put exit; on top of the index.php the page is totally blank, without error, so it is not being merged with the response by Apache or something. Also setting the error reporting in index/config has no effect (I realize that this is generally a bad idea, and would not leave production with a workaround like this).

My guess is that the error might be some kind of a cached artifact. But this WooCommerce has no cache plugins installed so far... I have only a minor experience with Wordpress, I do know the basics, but debugging this type of issues is a terrible pain. I would appreciate any tips suggesting where should I look.

Additional information worth mentioning: shared hosting on GoDaddy (not my choice...), php 5.6.

Comment: your right, it may not change because of some cache, its as if `error_log` is being outputted from within the theme (iffy). a quick search of that error found many results, so im guessing the booklovers theme is not correctly calling the turdpress core before using the add_action function within the widget on line 8..

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, the `error_log` inside the theme was being prepended to the response. I found it out this morning when I finally downloaded all the files (godaddy's ftp transfer rate is a joke) and did grep.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. A theme's `error_log` file was being prepended to the response.